# Xamarin android running very slow

Tags: xamarin

I made an app in xamarin and its running slow on some devices anybody knows why this is happening?

The code is:
(This is in absolute layout)

```
 View view = FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.view);
 view.SetX(1000);
 while(view.GetX() >= -200)
 {
 view.SetX(view.GetX - 10);
 await Task.Delay(1);
 }
```

Comment: Do you know which types of devices pose problems?

Comment: You are spamming a coordinate every 1 ms. that is a bit too tight.

Comment: As  Cheesebaron stated 1ms is too tight, in terms of updating a view's position that is `1000 Hz`, there are no Android devices that have screen refresh rates that high.

Comment: I changed the delay to 5 milisec and its work smooth thank you!